# Top bar review counter isn't updating

Tags: support, reviewing

I've encountered some odd behavior on the main site, and it's not something I've seen before. Here's what I see:

> [image: An "11" appears next to "review" in the top bar]

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but it's been vacillating between 10 and 13 for a few days now. There are no review tasks, and I definitely haven't skipped anything that wouldn't be handled by someone else by now.

As far as I can tell, this isn't a duplicate of the other "it's caching" posts, since it's been far, far too long for that to matter, as far as I know.

What would cause this indicator not to update when there are no reviews left to complete? I'm lost on this, and it's bothering me.

Comment: Mark this as [status-bydesign], even though it's old. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are review tasks, but you aren't seeing them. Since you're a newly moderator, the only reason why you wouldn't be seeing a review item would be if you've already acted on them¹ (for close and reopen, that includes having cast a close/reopen vote before becoming a moderator). Note that [the review counter is not personalized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726).

I see 6 close items, 1 reopen item, 1 low quality item and 1 suggested edit. There are presumably a few more that I've already acted on. Now that I've gone through the close and reopen queues, I see that e.g. you voted in the review queue on [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/1343) [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/1344) [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/1351) — not on [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/1297) so presumably there you cast a close vote outside the queue.

You can check [recent history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) (for each queue) and browse for uncompleted items. Offhand I don't think there's a page that displays all pending review items.

¹  <sub>or (I think) for first posts, late answers and low quality if it was your own post, or if it was your own suggested edit, but this doesn't apply to the close and reopen queues.</sub>

Comment: Huh, that's really odd. It jumped up a few days ago, and I hadn't acted then. But I believe you are correct, since this is what you see. Thank you!